# how to export blade in PDF with its css in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, css, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to export in pdf a page I have which looks like this[image]
but when I export it to PDF using DomPDF, it is like this:
[image]

how can this be done?
I am aware for PrinceXML but I want something free or that I can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all your stylings inside your blade instead of including as an external file.

[Wkhtml2pdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is also a good option

Comment: I've done that and wkhtml2pdf needs to be downloaded in pc, I want files thru composer